# How to check if element is currently dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to be able to check whether or not an event is occurring at the time a function is called. I have a function being called when my custom scroll bar is being dragged using .draggable() up and down and I also have a function being called when my container is scrolling. The problem is that both run at the same time which makes it act buggy.

So my question is how do I do an "if" statement checking whether or not the scroll bar is currently being dragged so I can stop it from executing the rest of the function's code?

I am not asking if an element has an event "binded" to it or not, but rather if that event is being triggered at a particular moment.

Can I do this? Or do I need to take another approach?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
$('.container').scroll(function(){
    //get the heights of the container and it's contents and the difference
    //get the height of the scroll bar and it's container and the difference
    //declare the top property of scroll bar from this info
});
function scrolly() {
    //get the heights of the elements described above
    //declare the scrollTop of the container
}
$('.bar').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',    
    drag: function() {
        scrolly();
    }
});
```

Comment: you can get that within you `drag` function, because `drag` fires when dragging continues

Comment: It's not clear what your other function is doing, but if they are both involved in scrolling, could you possibly just merge them together?

Comment: I probably should've made it more clear that the scroll bar has a container and the .container element is another element completely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

You can use this condition to find out if your bar is being dragged:

```
if ($('.bar').is('.ui-draggable-dragging')) {
    return; // bar is being dragged
}
```

Comment: It returns `true` even in the `stop` callback for draggable, because jquery ui calls `stop` before calling `_clear` which removes this class. Any other alternate solution for `stop` handler ?

Comment: @coding_idiot my first instincts would say that inside the stop handler you probably _should_ assume it's not being dragged anymore ;-)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, `drag` and `stop` are calling the same function, in which I'm doing different actions depending on whether dragging is still going on or not. As of now, I've added a class in `start` and removed in `stop` to take care of it :)